# How do I reconnect a linked .blend file?

Tags: linked-data

Is there a way to reconnect a linked .blend file that has been moved from its original location?

I have all my files linked together, but I now need them in separate folders, is there a way I can move them without them becoming disconnected, or is there a way I can reconnect them once they are moved?

Thanks!